# Should i use instanceof in this scenario or i need to use polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, instanceof

Suppose I have an Account class,

```
public class Account {
   void Print();
}
```

and I have derived two subclasses from it i.e. SavingsAccount and CheckingAccount.

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account{
   void Print();
}

public class CheckingAccount extends Account{
   void Print();
}
```

Now suppose I have a driver class lets say SimulateAccounts which has an array list of type Account,

```
public class SimulateAccounts{
   ArrayList<Node> myAccounts = new ArrayList<Node>();
   void simulate()
   { //suppose some function has added added 5 savingAccounts and 10 checkingsAccounts in myAccounts arraylist

   }
```

Now my question is that I want to find the count of the type savingAccounts and checkingAccounts in arraylist myAccounts in the above function of simulate, I can do this by using instanceof function. But I am confused over using it as I have read on numerous places that using instanceof is bad practice and code smell, so how can I fit polymorphism into it to avoid using instanceof or is it ok to use. Moreover if I use instance of and in future name of savingsAccount changes I need to also update my this code in simulation function! So what should I do here. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C# (your naming conventions indicate both Java and C#), you can just use `.OfType<CheckingAccount>().Count`.

But sure, go ahead and use `instanceof`. This isn't why it should be used with caution, it's when you define subclass-specific behaviour without providing an implementation in the class itself.

For example:

```
if(account instanceof CheckingAccount)
{
    // Do something
} else if(account instanceof SavingsAccount) {
    // Do another thing
}
```

As opposed to

```
account.DoAccountTypeSpecificThing();
```

What you want to do makes sense.

Comment: The use of the keyword `extends` clearly indicates Java

Comment: See the revision history.

Comment: I am using Java but the the question is more on can instanceof be avoided in the case I gave?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enum` to avoid `instanceof`:

```
public enum AccountType
{
   Check, Saving
}


public class Account 
{
   void Print();
   AccountType getAccountType();
}

public class SavingsAccount extends Account
{
  void Print(){};

  AccountType getAccountType()
  {
     return AccountType.Saving;
  }
}

public class CheckingAccount extends Account
{
  void Print(){};

  AccountType getAccountType()
  {
     return AccountType.Check;
  }
}
```

Now, if you want to know the type of an `Account` instance:

```
Account a = ...

switch(a.getAccountType())
{
 case Check:
   // do something specific to checking account
   break;

 case Saving:
   //do something specific to saving account
   break;

 default:
   break;
}
```

BTW, the use of `extends` to inherits classes is even worse than using `instanceof` in my opinion.

Comment: what should be used instead of extends?

Comment: It is just my opinion but I usually avoid extending class. I prefer implementing interface.